# How to display image N-D array in front end using React JS

Tags: python, reactjs, frontend, streaming, backend

I'm working on a project where my backend code is written in python and output generated n-d array which are nothing but images. I need to render those images in front end using React JS typically. Please note that I have a lot of image data and saving it as a file cannot be a scalable solution. I need to process it directly to front end. Is that possible?

Example of data:

```
[[[0 0 0...79 29 30]
  [0 0 0...97 22 20]
  [0 0 0...74 25 0]]]
```

I would need to send this data to the front end process and display the image.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to save the array as an image file and then display that image file via React.

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for your answer. By saving the array we would be occupying space and it would not be effective as I'm dealing with lot of data and this approach cannot be scalable, can we directly process it to front end without saving it as a file?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to store your `image_array` in the form of an Image file formate.  And then you can display them with an Image URL configured via Media files from Django Backend and then you can fetch the URLs very easily by getting requests on the frontend side.

> This article to [Covert Array into ImageFile](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-a-numpy-array-to-an-image/) can also help you to
> covert image_array into Images
>
> [Managing files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/) From Django Documentation

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for your answer. By saving the array we would be occupying space and it would not be effective as I'm dealing with lot of data and this approach cannot be scalable, can we directly process it to front end without saving it as a file?